# How to restore a store application temporary files after uninstalling the app?

Tags: windows-10, restore, system-restore

I have Win 10 Pro, and I've recently decided to reinstall Drawboard PDF editor application (from windows store ) for some reasons, but I acidentally removed some "temporary files" along with the uninstall (My pdf files which I haven't saved unfortunately) and they're now gone. I've tried Recuva and many other softwares to get back the files which were in Users/..../AppData/Local/Packages/Drawboard Folder, but no luck. Tried system restore couples of times, no luck as well. What can I do to restore my files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My pdf files which I haven't saved unfortunately ....  they're now
> gone. I've tried Recuva and many other software to get back the files  ....   Tried system restore couples of times, no luck as well.

So now at this point, and because Windows overwrites file locations it deems deleted, the files are gone.

Sorry, but that is the very hard lesson of saving files in a safe location and backups.